# CSS image not showing on page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, visual-studio, background-image

I might have the path incorrect, but I drag and dropped the image from its folder to the css background property, so it should be correct. It looks good, but not sure. If I load another image from a https url seen in commented out code, it works fine!

If I have the correct path, could it be something about the image security or permissions? I copied the image from another folder over to App_Data/Images/.
I'm not getting any javascript console error or anything in the console saying the image couldn't be found.

```css
.centerMarker {
  position: absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background: url('../App_Data/Images/meetups.png') no-repeat;
  /*this does not work*/
  /*background: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png) no-repeat;*/
  /*this works*/
  /*center the marker*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height: 34px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

site.css is where the css is located and you can see from this pic that the images are in Images in App_Data.

[image]

Here is what I see in the DOM explorer in Dev tools in IE.
Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a root relative url rather than an absolute path. So instead of starting at the current file, climbing up the tree, and going back down, it will start at the top and work down.

```
background: url('/App_Data/Images/meetups.png') no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: url('~/App_Data/Images/meetups.png') no-repeat;
```

Your path does look correct for your file structure, but once the site is rendered on the server, your structure may be a bit different (for example, the Content folder may just be where all your views are stored, but be omitted from actual paths).

Comment: I just tried both of your suggestions with no luck. I had to click on 'unblock' in the pictures properties. Do you think it might have something to do with the permissions? Even though I'm not getting anything in the console about errors?

Comment: Bummer. Then it may be the permissions issue you were alluding to. Try moving the image out of the App_Data folder and into a new directory such as /images (and remember to update your paths to /images/meetups.png) as well

Comment: nope, still nothing! I moved it up one folder to App_Data/meetups.png and updated the path in the background property

Comment: When I double click on the image in Solution Explorer I get a popup message that says "The system cannot find the file specified" Is this typical or should VS open the image in its IDE or some other app? I can hover over the image and it displays a thumb!

Comment: Brian, can you check the URL path from the image I posted. It was taken from the DOM in IE's Dev tools

Comment: Try moving all the way outside of the App_Data folder.

Right click the .Web project, and create a new folder there so the new folder would reside at the same level as App_Data, App_Start, Content, etc.

Comment: YES! that worked, now I just have to figure out why? Maybe something with permissions on App_Data?

Comment: App_Data and App_Start (and others) are special folders that are used by ASP.NET for specific files to be found and used by the server while building the site, so ASP.NET doesn't let regular internet users access those folders.